# Reduce size of widgets in Plasma panel

Tags: kde, panel, plasma

Is there some way to reduce the size of the widgets in the plasma (KDE 16.04) panel?

I have a right-aligned panel and they appear to expand to fill the width, which also increases their height (what I don't like).

[image]

Comment: Could you try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1244369 ?

Comment: @palmerito0 No, that doesn't help. The problem is the icons are the same size as the panel itself. I want a larger panel with smaller icons. The top two should be small, I make it bigger for the other components.